# Remover elemento de un array almacenado en localStorage

Tags: javascript, array, local-storage

Estoy creando un boton que tiene que sacar del array favoritos de mi localstorage el ID de la pelicula que quiero remover.

Dentro del handler llamo a la clase lopo que tiene el mismo ID que quiero remover PERO FUERA del localstorage.
No se como hacer para eliminarlo.

Me dijeron que pruebe con un filter pero no me salio. Tendria que igualar myFav con list y preguntar si existe algo igual entonces sacarlo.

Se les ocurre algo ?

el LOG de LA LINEA 63 muestra el contenido de list y el log de la linea 64 myFav

[image: el LOG de LA LINEA 63 muestra el contenido de list y el log de la linea 64 myFav]

```
const RemoveFavHandler = (e) => {
    const elementoPadre = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    const myFav = elementoPadre.querySelector(".lopo").innerText;
    let localList=localStorage.getItem("favoritos");
        let list=JSON.parse(localList);
        console.log(list);
        console.log(myFav);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los elementos en el `localStorage` no pueden ser modificados, por lo tanto, necesitas sobrescribir el valor del array en `localStorage` cada vez que requieras modificar su valor. Basado en tu código, solamente debes agregar estas líneas:

```
const RemoveFavHandler = (e) => {
  const elementoPadre = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
  const myFav = elementoPadre.querySelector(".lopo").innerText;
  let localList=localStorage.getItem("favoritos");
  let list=JSON.parse(localList);
  list.splice(list.indexOf(myFav),1) // Elimina el elemento myFav del array ​list
  localStorage.setItem("favoritos", JSON.stringify(list))  // Sobrescribe el array de favoritos en el localStorage  
​}
```

Comment: muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor sería usar indexOf y splice, de esta manera:

```js
const RemoveFavHandler = (e) => {
    const elementoPadre = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    const myFav = elementoPadre.querySelector(".lopo").innerText;
    let localList = localStorage.getItem("favoritos");
    let list = JSON.parse(localList);
    // Busca el índice del elemento
    const favIdx = list.indexOf(myFav);
    // Elimina el elemento
    list.splice(favIdx, 1);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias !